# How to overwrite inferior-erlang-compile-outdir in erlang.el

Tags: emacs, erlang

I'm using erlang-mode. The beam is generated in the same folder with the source file which is in nested folders instead of just in folder *src*.

I think I should overwrite the *inferior-erlang-compile-outdir* in the erlang.el but I failed.

Following is my function:

```
(defun inferior-erlang-compile-outdir ()
  (let* (format "%s/ebin" (get-project-path))))
```

PS: *get-project-path* is a function to get the root path of my project.

===========update=================

```
(require-package 'erlang)

;; add include directory to default compile path.
(defvar erlang-compile-extra-opts
  '(bin_opt_info 
    debug_info
    (i . "../include")
    (i . "../../include")))

;; define where put beam files.
(defun inferior-erlang-compile-outdir ()
  (concat (get-closest-pathname) "/ebin" ))

(require 'erlang-start)


;;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; Get closest pathname of file
;;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
(defun* get-closest-pathname (&optional (file "Makefile"))
  (let ((dir (locate-dominating-file default-directory file)))
    (or dir default-directory)))
```

Comment: Could you specify "takes no effect"? Your updated code snippet does exactly what I understand you want it to do. What does your erlang shell output when you compile a file?

Comment: The same directory with source file. `c("/Users/suyejun/project/code/src/lib/lib_dungeon_rush", [{outdir, "/Users/suyejun/project/code/src/lib/"}, bin_opt_info, debug_info, {i, "../include"}, {i, "../../include"}]).`

Comment: I hope you do have a Makefile in your project root? Also what is "(require-package 'erlang)" ?

Comment: Yes, I have this file. require-package is a function borrowed from https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/master/init-elpa.el. It will automatically install the package if not exist. Let me check again.

Comment: Ok, I assumed it would actually require it. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct, `inferior-erlang-compile-outdir` defines where to place compiled files.
Though your use of `let*` is wrong. `let` lets you define scoped variables, in your case you don't need it at all. Just concat the two strings:

```
(defun inferior-erlang-compile-outdir ()
    (concat (get-project-path) "/ebin" ))
```

For future reference if you want to use `let` take a look at the [doc here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eintr.html#Parts-of-let-Expression).

But the erlang-mode is not loaded yet when you define it. So your function gets overwritten by the original once the erlang-mode is loaded. You have to define it **afterwards**. This should do it:

```
(eval-after-load "erlang"
  '(defun inferior-erlang-compile-outdir ()
     (concat (expand-file-name (get-closest-pathname)) "ebin")))
```

Comment: Sorry, I mistaken something. It takes no effect. Please see my update.